# Contenteditable only on left click

Tags: html, mouseevent, contenteditable

How can I enable `contenteditable` HTML element to work only on left mouse button click?

I tried `@click.right.stop` and `@click.right.prevent` from Vue.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to approach this problem differently. Instead of having `contenteditable` instanly. Add/remove the tag based on how you click the element. Add a normal `click` listener on the element and there toggle the `contenteditable` tag on the element.

And in the case of that you're already editing the field and want to click inside the text and not disable it again; you can do a check if the content is actually empty or not. If it's empty; you hide it again. But if it already contains text, you can keep it open. Or do some magic where you remember the initial edit state and check if it's changed since making editable. If it changed; you give the user a prompt of what to do (save or discard).